# Hide the zero values in a Scatter/Column chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I saw a bunch of sources that has similar question raised, none of them seem to have solve my issue. As you can see in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NxYh/105/
I have a chart with type scatter and data that has multiple '0' values. i would like to hide those 0 values(you can see the dots at the bottom) in such a way that only the non-0 values gets displayed on the chart. i tried few suggestions, none of them seem to show how to hide the dots for '0' values.
the one i tried:

```
 plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    var val = this.y;
                    if (val === 0) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    return val;
                },
            },
            treshold: 1
        }
    },
```

didnt work for me...any ideas?

Comment: Map 0s to nulls before you render the chart - see example http://jsfiddle.net/4NxYh/106/

Comment: thanks that worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving zeros in x values give `null` values.

No need of formatter also. working code : http://jsfiddle.net/0c83yagw/

like

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ["14.08", null, null, null, null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],

    }
```

You will have to format your data if any zeros to null

Comment: data comes in as a response from the api call, cannot control the values of 'x' when the data loads, hence i tried setting it to null manually after the data is loaded, but it doesnt work.

Comment: so i load the data in my series:[] (it loads as data:[0,0,01,0....] and then i tried to set it manually in the formatter: "var val = this.y;
                    if (val === 0) {
                        return null;
                    }"

Comment: Im not in front of computer now. I cant check now. Im commenting using mobile app. Will get back to you later.